# How do byte-sliced AES implementations work?

Tags: aes, implementation, bitslicing

While I understand the principle of bit-slicing, several papers  mention byte-sliced AES implementations (see e.g. [Homomorphic Evaluation of the AES Circuit](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/099.pdf) and [Fast Implementations of AES on Various Platforms](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f7fe/499b7c52cce4dc2b25d7182ffbca797ae504.pdf)).

However, I don't clearly understand how byte-slicing works. Especially, one can read in the above mentioned papers that:

- 16 blocks are processed in parallel
- The permutations in ShiftRows/MixColumns are now "for free"

Could someone explain how byte-slicing works in the case of AES, and how it allows to process 16 blocks in parallel without computing the ShiftRows?

Comment: I am standing now on the same problem. You got any understanding / answers to your problem?